# What are some free eBooks to help my kids learn Chinese?

Tags: mandarin, books

My son, who is 6 years old, really loves learning Chinese now.

I want to find some free Chinese teaching e-books for my children. What resources did you use if you learn Chinese?

Please share it, thank you.

Comment: To be honest, we're not good at answering these questions.  I think you'll get better answers at [Reddit r/ChineseLanguage](https://www.reddit.com/r/ChineseLanguage/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try to ask questions there afterward.

Comment: You can register with Lingo Bus, and they have lots of great free learning material for children.

Comment: 声律启蒙 is the most classic pronunciation book in China from ancient times to the present. No need to understand it, just follow along, and it's thin.